# Retain scroll position while model is updated in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i have a list of teams and user can add a team to list of teams. the problem i having is that when i add an item to an list, angular re-renders the list and scroll position is reset to the top.

this is the template

```
 <div ng-controller="scores">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="team in teams">
      {{team.name}}: 
      <button ng-click="decr(team)">-</button>
      {{team.score}}
      <button ng-click="incr(team)">+</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <a href="#" ng-click="add()">(+)Add Team</a>
  </div>
```

here is the controller code

```
function scores($scope){
  $scope.teams = [
    {name:'red', score:100},
    {name:'blue', score:100},
    {name:'green', score:100}
  ];

  $scope.decr= function(team){team.score-=1;};
  $scope.incr= function(team){team.score+=1;};  
  $scope.add= function(){$scope.teams.push({name:"...", score:100});};    

}
```

you can see working example here. http://jsbin.com/asedib/5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have `href="#"`, which resets the anchor / scroll position to the top of the page every time you click the link.

I see two easy solutions:

The easiest is to change the anchor to a button.  This still makes it clear that this is a clickable element, but without the anchor element:

```
<button ng-click="add()">(+) Add Team</button>
```

If you prefer the anchor-style appearance, you can remove the `href="#"`, but then update your CSS to style the non-anchor link to *look* like a link.  Something like this:

```
<a ng-click="add()" class="clickable">(+) Add Team</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
a, a.clickable {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Both of these solutions solve the immediate problem without any extra JavaScript.

Comment: Great. button and anchor without href="#", both solves the problem. Thank you very much.